# Count duplicated value in Python considering sequence

Tags: python, string, list, counter

I have `string` value as:

```
s = 'asdabbdasfababbabb'
```

I've split the `str` by using below code, than get result as below :

```
n = 3
split_strings = [s[index : index + n] for index in range(0, len(s), n)]

['asd', 'abb', 'das', 'fab', 'abb', 'abb']
```

**What I need to achieve:**

I want to count duplicated value consiering the sequence such as :

```
({'asd': 1, 'abb': 1, 'das': 1, 'fab': 1, 'abb' : 2})
```

However, if I use `Counter()` it counts the duplicated value but, does not seems to consider the sequence of list:

```
Counter({'asd': 1, 'abb': 3, 'das': 1, 'fab': 1})
```

How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: Did you know that a dictionary cannot store two identical keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store duplicate keys in a dict. If you are willing to have a list of tuples, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['asd', 'abb', 'das', 'fab', 'abb', 'abb']

counts = [(k, len([*g])) for k, g in groupby(lst)]
print(counts) # [('asd', 1), ('abb', 1), ('das', 1), ('fab', 1), ('abb', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `itertools.groupby` function is a favorite, but perhaps future readers might appreciate an algorithm for actually finding these groupings:

```py
def groups(*items):
    i = 0
    groups = []
    while i < len(items):
        item = items[i]
        j = i + 1
        count = 1
        while j < len(items):
            if items[j] == item:
                count += 1
                j += 1
            else:
                break
        i = j
        groups.append((item, count))
    return groups
```